# How to deserialize JSON to a "semi dynamic" object using JSON.NET on VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, json.net

Well, i want to deserialize the JSON into .Net object. I've using a class for it, but it seems like throwing an error.

`Me._konten` contains this string

```
{
   "status": true,
   "content": {
       "status": "up",
       "ver": "3.0.1",
       "gen": "a"
   }
}
```

here's the converter

```vb
    Public Async Function JSONify() As Task(Of APIResponseJSON)
        Dim hasil As Object = Await _
            Task.Run(Function()
                         Return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of APIResponseJSON)(Me._Konten)
                     End Function)
        Return hasil
    End Function
```

so, the content part is really unpredictable, it may be a array, or  other object.
This was the class that i've made:

```vb
  Public Class APIResponseJSON
       Public Property status As Boolean = False
       Public Property content As Object = New Object
  End Class
```

and then, when i test it, this shows that the "status" in the "content" are not found.
[Throwed Exception by UnitTesting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFqru.jpg)

So How to make the `content` member are really dynamic?

**EDIT**

the content may be like this tooo

```
{
    "status": false,
    "content": {
        "detail": {
            "status": "Not Found",
            "code": 404,
            "text": "HTTP 404 (GET \/info)",
            "trace": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider change content object to Dictionary(of String, String). Here's the example:-

```
Public Class APIResponseJSON
   Public Property status As Boolean = False
   Public Property content As New Dictionary(of String, String)
End Class
```

It will convert content into Dictionary(of String, string) and you can use Content("status") to get the desire value.

Reference: [How can I deserialize JSON to a simple Dictionary<string,string> in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net)

**UPDATE**

```
Public Class APIResponseJSON
   Public Property status As Boolean = False
   Public Property content As New Dictionary(of String, String)
   Public Property exception As New Dictionary(of String, Dictionary(of string, string))
End Class
```

You can separate the data with error message by using "Status". For example:-

```
If obj.Status = True Then
   ' read from content
Else
   ' read from exception
End If
```

Comment: it did the job. but sometimes when i accessed other "404" url, the response changes and it gives error. (i've updated the post). when i create a new test unit, it throw exception like this http://i.imgur.com/gUBV6iX.png

Comment: I would suggest you to separate content. Please see the update above. Hope this helps. :)